# What does "implicitly" mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Here’s the context:

*Finally, if an institutionalized child is transferred into a family setting, can he or she recoup undeveloped capacities? **Implicitly**, poignantly: Can a person unloved in childhood learn to love?*

I think it should be "explicitly" because the following question is more explicit and straightforward.

If even more context would help:

*In the decade after the fall of Ceauescu, the new Romanian government welcomed Western child-development experts to simultaneously help and study the tens of thousands of children still warehoused in state care. Researchers hoped to answer some long-standing questions: Are there sensitive periods in neural development, after which the brain of a deprived child cannot make full use of the mental, emotional, and physical stimulation later offered? Can the effects of “maternal deprivation” or “caregiver absence” be documented with modern neuroimaging techniques? Finally, if an institutionalized child is transferred into a family setting, can he or she recoup undeveloped capacities? Implicitly, poignantly: Can a person unloved in childhood learn to love?*

Comment: Perhaps the writer understands the latter question to be present in the former, as if it were folded up inside, which is the radical meaning of *implicit.* Or perhaps  some constraint on the formulation of the question (such as requirements for an empirical research question) prevent the latter question from being the final or official formulation, but is the intended question nevertheless. We might need more context to say which or both.

Comment: It means that the researchers literally asked the other questions.  The last one was implicit in the work they did.

Comment: It means just what [*implicitly*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implicitly) normally means.